# One way publishing in rebus?

Tags: rebus

By reading the [Handing off work](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Handing-off-work) section in wiki, it seems that you can do one way publishing in rebus with one way mode. But I thought one way mode only allows bus.send?

If in a scenario, where I have two applications both can publish **SomethingHappened** message, but only one of the application should handle the reply from ProcessManager, e.g. **DoSomethingElse**, how should I configure rebus for both applications?

Regards

Yin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I thought one way mode only allows bus.send?

Nothing will prevent you from doing a `bus.Publish` from a one-way client as long as it has a properly set up subscription storage. And if something else populates that subscription storage with some subscriptions (e.g. you, by inserting them manually in the db, or by having another publisher handle subscribe/unsubscribe) then something might actually happen when you publish ;)

> how should I configure rebus for both applications?

Without having a totally clear image of your scenario, I'm thinking that

- one publisher, A, has an input queue: `publisherA`
- the other publisher, B, has no input queue (i.e. it's a one-way client)
- the two publishers share their subscription storage (e.g. a table in SQL Server)
- the two publishers publish messages from assembly `StuffToPublish`
- other endpoints have an endpoint mapping that maps `StuffToPublish` to `publisherA` - therefore, a `bus.Subscribe` with an event type from `StuffToPublish` will make publisher A establish the subscription
- published messages from A and B will go to the same subscribers because they share their subscription storage

If you want publisher A to handle replies even though the event was published by publisher B, you can make B supply the `rebus-return-address` header (which would otherwise automatically be set, had B had an input queue) like so:

```
bus.AttacheHeader(someEvent, Headers.ReturnAddress, "publisherA");
```

This way, replies will be sent to the `publisherA` input queue.